# How to load a javascript file only in some ejs templates?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, ejs

I am building an app with the help of node, express and ejs. The structure of my app is in this way that I used a `footer.ejs` file in all pages (templates) and in that file I have a code like this:

> footer.ejs

```
<!-- bootstrap js CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    <!-- some other codes -->   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But in some of my pages I need some **js** codes. Because I don't want to load them in un-related pages, I decided to add the `<script>` tags of them individually on that page only like the code below:

> information.ejs:

```html
<!-- the html tags of this page (called information.ejs) are here -->
<!-- ... -->
<!-- end of html tags -->
<script src="/javascripts/upload.js"></script> <!-- this is the script codes that only need in this page -->
<%- include('include/footer') %>
```

That works fine. But now I need some functionality of `bootstrap.js` in my `upload.js` script. The problem here is that `upload.js` is loaded `before` the `bootstrap.js` and I could not use the functionality of bootstrap in my script.

To solve that problem I decided to define a variable called `infoId` and send that to `information.ejs` like below in my express router file:

```js
router.get('/dashboard2/:infoId', (req, res) => {
        res.render("information", { 
            infoId: req.params.infoId,
        });
})
```

And then deleted the script tag from the end of `information.ejs` file and added it in `footer.ejs` like below:

> new footer.ejs:

```html
<!-- bootstrap js CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- added new -->
    <% if(infoId !== undefined) { %> 
    <% if(infoId == "information") { %>
    <script src="/javascripts/upload.js"></script>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <!-- some other codes -->   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case I get the error of `variable infoId is undefined` when I navigate to other routes (pages). Could I fix this problem without sending the `infoId` variable to all other routes?

Comment: Usually bootstrap and other third party libs are loaded in the header.

Comment: @ggorlen The [official bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) says that use ```<script>``` tag before the closing ```</body>```.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that. How about doing that, but then adding `defer` to your `<script>` tags so they run after the bootstrap script?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for your comment, that's working fine for me. But I if we use ```defer```, then we could not be confident about the order of loading of scripts that use that attribute? Is that right?

Comment: "Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document." according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).